# Facebook c# client getting script error during authorization

Tags: c#, facebook, authorization

I have a c# client application using MS's Facebook library that has been working fine for a while (this particular form was last changed on May 6th, and was working during my last test cycle last week).  This is in a kiosk app (still in development, fortunately) that has an embedded web browser so users can authenticate and authorize our app.  Today, I started getting script error pop-ups when you click on either button on the authorize page.

So I go to the login page, user authenticates, all is good, then it goes to the authorize page " would like to post privately on your behalf", still good, however, when you click okay or skip, up comes a pop-up that says

```
An error has occurred in the script on this page
Line: 5
Character: 878
Error: "Access is denied."
URL: https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yG/r/q0zNT1kK_7g.js.
```

Now the pop-up has the normal "Do you want to continue running scripts on this page" Yes/No options, but again, it's stuck.  Click yes or no, and it doesn't matter, the pop-up keeps popping up, and I have to kill the process manually.

I haven't changed my code, but may have changed some app settings while reviewing the "breaking changes" list and enabling that, but if so, I'm not sure what I could have done to break this.  I've gone back through and played with some of the settings, to no obvious avail.

The other side of this problem that's also frustrating is that since I never actually complete the oauth process, I never get my access token.  However, something is cookied, and it thinks the user is still logged in.  Since I don't have an access token, I can't log them out, so now everytime I go to the login page, it blows past it straight to the authorize page.  Obviously, if I can get past the script error, I can get my token and log the user out.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Edit:
I took the URL over to Chrome and it worked fine, so I grabbed the .js in question to find the offending code.  The problem is a "window.resizeBy(w,x)", and some quick searching looks like IE may be blocking this intentionally (at least old versions, when I tried it in an IE 10 real browser it worked, too).  Interestingly, in Chrome (but not in IE), when it first hit one of the authorization screens, I got the following message:

> You are using a display type of 'popup' in a large browser window or
>   tab. For a better user experience, show this dialog with our
>   JavaScript SDK without specifying an explicit display type. The SDK
>   will choose the best display type for each environment. Alternatively,
>   set height and width on your window.open() call to properly size this
>   dialog if you have special requirements precluding you from using the
>   SDK. This message is only visible to developers of your application.

This makes me wonder: if I can figure out how to grab the window.open in the embedded browser, and if I can set the size explicitly as suggested, will it then skip this resize causing the problems.  Off to more research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the time spent in Chrome was (as usual) more valuable than any other browser.  Since this was using MS's Facebook client, and not the JS SDK, there was no easy way to get to the window.open.  The other key that the message in Chrome gave was that we're using type "popup".  Changed that to type "page", and no more script error.  The authorizations show in their own JS pop-ups, which should be fine.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion of solution.  Do you know any solution for this exact scenario for WPF WebBrowser?